# Finder Single Click Sometimes Renames File

Tags: finder, click

OSX 10.14.6
MacBrook Pro (15-inch, 2017)

Using either USB mouse or trackpad, occasionally in Finder a single click is acting like I've selected "rename." I understand if I single click a previously selected item this is the expected behavior but this is if the item is unselected.

This also happened on my previous 13-inch occasionally. I can't figure out how to replicate but curious if anyone else has run into this and/or has any ideas. I have to resort to keyboard arrows and shortcuts to do anything with the file (other than rename of course!).

Sometimes it's a few files within the folder while other files in the same folder are behaving as expected.

Comment: This has never happened to me while using dozens of Macs over several years.  Since it's happening to you on 2 different Macs and doesn't happen with every single-click, it looks like you're doing something to cause this, perhaps an inadvertent dbl-click?

Comment: I'm being very careful to only single click including just one tap of the trackpad. What's strange is that once it starts happening for a particular file, it's impossible to single-click it again without triggering rename until I restart. I can't find any evidence through searches of anyone else having this issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on macos 10.14.6. Only option was to restart.

Comment: Happens to me as well. Input source doesn't seem to matter (built-in track pad, external trackpad, or external mouse). If it's not a good time to restart, I'll pop into [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com) or [iTerm](https://iterm2.com) to do what I need.

Comment: @duozmo do you by any chance use SizeUp? That's the only app I have that might be a suspect.